# Encrypted files in Win10 Explorer does not show in green anymore?

Tags: windows-10

After upgrading to Win10 from Win8.1 I notice that the files and folders encrypted display as any others (black on white). On previous Windows versions they were displayed with green text.

Is that a characteristic of Win10 or it can be customized somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Win10: search "file explorer options"   (or ask Cortana)

open the `File Explorer Options` dialog

Select the `"View"` panel and make sure the following option is checked:

```
[x] Show encrypted or compressed NTFS files in color
```